# WPF InitializeComponent performance problems

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I have a WPF application (.NET 4) which has a main window, and inside that main window shows many smaller `UserControls`. Various actions performed by the user cause the `UserControls` which are displayed to get replaced by different other controls with different data.

I am running into performance problems however, when switching these controls. The WPF dispatcher thread goes to 100% CPU while loading controls. On older machines, or with larger numbers of controls, this can result in the application appearing to lock up for as long as 30 seconds!

Profiling indicates that almost all of this CPU time is spent calling the various `InitializeComponent` methods of all the different `UserControls` - no one control appears to be vastly worse than any other, they all seem to take between 0.2 and 0.5 seconds (on my dev machine with a fast processor and good graphics card).

As far as I know, `InitializeComponent` is where WPF actually loads the compiled xaml into memory.

I'm at a loss for what to do here. I'd like to pre-initialize things on a background thread, but all WPF controls must be created and used on the dispatcher thread, so I don't think this is possible.

Otherwise it looks like the only options I have are to delete all my xaml??

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: without knowing more about your app (specific details + code), I can only imagine that you either have a huge amount of user controls (+50) and/or very heavy data bindings. So the only answer would be to redesign your application logic. What you must also understand is that WPF is absolutely crap when it comes to large amount of controls/data, because it is heavily unoptimized (I guess it's too high-level of a framework). Perhaps try WinForms for your app (which is a bit better) or write everything in native c++/directx (a'la Photoshop, AutoCAD style)

Comment: http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/ - I guess that the controls are being loaded, the rendering generated and maybe cached. It does mention PIX (a WPF perf tool) that you might like to try.

Answer (score 4):

To revisit this - we do have many complex controls on the screen, but we can't just get rid of them to keep WPF happy!

Further experimentation with profiling showed that using Custom controls (basically just a C# class deriving directly from `Control` and defining the UI in a `Generic.xaml` themes file only seem to incur the hit of loading and parsing the XAML once. Thereafter, each control just applies the pre-existing theme.

Custom controls are much more difficult to work with than UserControls, but this did seem to help our load performance a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The `InitializeComponent` method takes time because it needs to insert the control in the Visual/Logical tree and assure all bindings, themes, expected resources etc.

My only suggestion is - is it possible to initialise all potential controls from the outset, and then show/hide them when needed using the `Visibility` property ?

You can use Freezable for caching some UI, but if they are user controls then most likely you will want your user to interact with them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we initially had been loading all the controls up front then only showing the ones we need. Then there was a gigantic lag (over a minute on slower machines) when the form was first shown, which was an even worse user experience than the current behavior :-(

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I had a window with a load time about 1500 ~ 2000 ms, the problem was the **icons**.

I was using a tool for converting SVG to XAML DrawingImage elements, and a user control with a large resource dictionary with a drawing image for every used icon

The InitializeComponent was so slow because it had to parse that large XAML file containing all the vector data for the images

Hope it helps.